# How to output text in ReactJS without wrapping it in span

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my ReactJS-based application I do:

```
var _ = React.DOM;
_.span(null, 'some text', _.select(null, ...));
```

The problem is: 'some text' is wrapped in additional span element in the DOM. Is there any way to avoid this behavior and just output raw text?

To be clear: I want to output

```
<span>some text<select>...</select></span>
```

not

```
<span><span>some text</span><select>...</select></span>
```

Comment: Looking at the React Docs. the method "span" is intended to create a <span>.

Maybe try using the DOM.text() method?

Comment: No, text outputs <text>. To be clear: I want to output `<span>some text<select>...</select></span>` not `<span><span>some text</span><select>...</select></span>`.

Comment: It's not possible. React needs to be able to give a unique ID to every piece of content, and text that is a sibling of another element is not addressable because [Text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) have no attributes.

Comment: What are you trying to do that the `<span>` prevents?

Comment: @ssorallen post that as an answer :-)

Comment: You cannot do this in react.  All text must be inside some kind of element on it's own - you can't have text, then an element.  To be honest this is best practice for html anyway - `<div><span>text</span><select></select></div>` is better than `<span>text<select></select></span>`

Comment: Thank you guys, post the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Update:** This is now "fixed" in **React v15 (2016-04-06)** – now comment nodes are added around each piece of text, but it is no longer wrapped in a `<span>` tag.

> We received some amazing contributions from the community in this release, and we would like to highlight [this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5753) by [Michael Wiencek](https://github.com/mwiencek) in particular. Thanks to Michael’s work, React 15 no longer emits extra `<span>` nodes around the text, making the DOM output much cleaner. This was a longstanding annoyance for React users so it’s exciting to accept this as an outside contribution.

[Full release notes.](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html)

---

This is currently a technical limitation of React; it wraps any floating text nodes in a span so that it can assign it an ID and refer back to it later. In a future version of React hopefully we can remove this restriction.

Comment: See also [#1236](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1236) which  is a related issue.

Comment: Where there's a will there's a way. Couldn't insert code here in the comment field, so added one below.

Comment: @Kokodoko Then add a span around them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can hard code the html as a last resort.

```
<option value={value} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value}}></option>
```

Comment: `<option value={value}>{value}</option>` already doesn't add a span.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. If you're hell bent on doing this, and accept the limitation that you cannot access props or state, you could do this:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    displayName:"Statics",
    statics: {
         customRender: function(foo) {
              return React.renderToStaticMarkup(<div 
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: foo.bar }}/>);
         }
    },
    render: function () {
        return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
               <Component.customRender bar="<h1>This is rendered
               with renderToStaticMarkup</h1>" />}} />
    }
});
```

renderToStaticMarkup will not insert any spans or react-dataid, and is meant for static server rendering. It's probably not a great idea to do this, but there you go.

> *renderToStaticMarkup*
>   Similar to renderToString, except this doesn't create extra DOM
>   attributes such as data-react-id, that React uses internally. This is
>   useful if you want to use React as a simple static page generator, as
>   stripping away the extra attributes can save lots of bytes.

Check the result at: http://learnreact.robbestad.com/#/static

Comment: If you just render `<h1>This is rendered without renderToStaticMarkup</h1>`, that doesn't make any spans either.

Answer (score 0):

I Changed the version of react and react-dom and worked perfect

```
"react": "^15.0.1",
"react-dom": "^15.0.1"
```

Comment: Yep, React >= 15 doesn't create those spans anymore.