# ReactJS create element

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, createelement

I'm creating an page with ReactJS, but I have this question:

I did this code:

```
 React.DOM.h2({}, 'Edit Store ', 
     React.DOM.span({}, ' (ID: ' + this.state.store.id + ')')
 )
```

And the result is:

```
 <h2> 
    <span>EDIT STORE</span>
    <span> (id: 123456) </span> 
 </h2>
```

But what I want is:

```
 <h2> 
    EDIT STORE 
    <span> (id: 123456) </span> 
 </h2>
```

How can I have the second result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ouput text in ReactJS without wrapping it in span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469474/how-to-ouput-text-in-reactjs-without-wrapping-it-in-span)

Comment: This is possible using React 15+ https://jsfiddle.net/noblehop/6L0ex1yL/1/. More context on the [react 15 blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html)

Comment: `v('h2', 'Edit Store ', v('span', \`(ID: ${this.state.store.id})\`))`

Comment: or `<h2>Edit Store <span>(ID: {this.state.store.id} )</span></h2>` in jsx

Answer (score 0):

I Changed the version of react and react-dom, like Nick Tomlin suggered me, and worked perfect

```
"react": "^15.0.1",
"react-dom": "^15.0.1",
```