# React creating span where it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a component to show a sort of Table of Contents. I'm struggling with react for it is creating a span tag where, in my understanding, it shouldn't.

The rendering functions is:

```
render() {
         return(
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.contents.map(function(li, i) {

                        let subItems = li.subItems.map(function(subLi, j) {
                            return (
                                <li>
                                    <span>{subLi.title}</span>
                                </li>
                            )
                        }, this);

                        return (
                            <li tabIndex={i}>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right" />{li.title}</span>
                                <ul class="subitens">
                                    {subItems}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        );
                    }, this)
                }
            </ul>
        );
```

The line `<span><i class="fa fa-caret-right" />{li.title}</span>` is creating the following structure:

```
<span>
    <i></i>
    <span>Parent 1</span>
</span>
```

And I would like:

```
<span><i></i> Parent 1</span>
```

That `span` around my text is messing with my CSS.

I wrapped it up on a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpcvzsLo/

Any ideas on what am I getting wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have same probem too, but this is how react work. it wrap all text inside of span, instead of text node creation. Not sure that it possible to fix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469474/how-to-ouput-text-in-reactjs-without-wrapping-it-in-span

Comment: :(
Thanks degr, thought I getting some basic JSX wrong...

Comment: try this: `<i class="fa fa-caret-right">{li.title}</i>' dont use the `span`

Comment: I am actually using `react-html-attrs` plugin in my project so that shouldn't be a problem (forgot when pasting to jsfiddle). I tried with className and got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
                      return (
                                <li tabIndex={i}>
                                    <span className="fa fa-caret-right">
                                        {li.title}
                                     </span>
                                    <ul className="subitens">
                                        {subItems}
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpcvzsLo/4/ (included Font Awesome to show)

Output:

```
<span class="fa fa-caret-right" data-reactid=".0.1.0">Parent 2</span>
```

Comment: As you see, the text get's italic... Not exactly what I want. That <i> should be only for the icons

Comment: Yep, and then this is where CSS takes over to style the look and feel of what you want. I just worked from your example :) anyway, you found your solution.

Comment: Ah I see the mistake why it goes italic, I thought that was an li tag, changing it to <span> will work as a place holder

Comment: I added Font Awesome to show you what it'd look like. You would need to tweak the CSS slightly to get rid of the default bullet points for the Parent (or Child). I know upgrading to 0.15 solved all of your problems, but I think this will help others who doesn't have the luxury to upgrade right now

Comment: Thanks a lot @zerohero. That actually does solve this issue specifically. I will not accept for I think updating react is a better one because it will stop react spamming "spans", ok? But I really do appreciate your answer. It made me look in another way

Answer (score 0):

As @degr told, this is a known issue with old react versions. It emits  tags along with every text.

All I did was to update my React to 0.15 and it works.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason it wrapped the text in a span is because it wasn't contained in the <li> tag. You used the <li> as purely a placeholder to show an image/bullet image. If you wrapped the title within the <li> it wouldn't have outputted the span either. Glad you came right.